# Visual Studio 2019 Schema Compare Crash

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, schema-compare

When I run the Visual Studio 2019 SQL Schema Compare tool, it correctly identifies the differences between 2 databases. Then whenever I try to "Update" or "Generate SQL" to update the schema on my target database, Visual Studio crashes.

Looking around it looks like this issue has been around in previous versions for a number of years. I tried applying the solutions I found online. One was to by unchecking the Option "Optimize rendering for screens with different densities" in Options - General. Another was to clear Visual Studio ComponentModelCache. Neither solution worked for me.

Is there a reliable way to get around this bug?

Alternatively, is there another (hopefully free) tool that will do this.  My needs are occasional so the VS solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get around the bug that crashes Visual Studio, either using "Update" or "Generate SQL" either in Visual Studio 2019 or (just checked) the newly released Visual Studio 2022.

Please post here if others are not getting this bug or if you have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I can feel you, this is very disruptive.

If you have a good idea what has changed you can filter the comparison. I can circumvent this by separating in 4 to 5 steps. 1) tables/triggers/index only 2) views only 3) scalar/table valued functions 4) stored procedures 5) users/roles/role memberships. After each step i rebuild and save all. If there are problems I fix them before continuing with further steps. The fixing on the spot is recommended if you have database unit tests.